# How to map Indentity ApplicationUser to Custom class

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I now have the following code, using EF 6:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public virtual ICollection<Client> Clients { get; set; }
}

    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection")
        {
        }
    }
```

Custom:

```
public class MembershipManagerDbContext : DefaultDbContext
{
    public MembershipManagerDbContext()
    {
    }

    // db entities
    public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Member> Members { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Payment> Payments { get; set; }
    public DbSet<PaymentType> PaymentTypes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Client> Client { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ClientPayment> ClientPayment { get; set; }
    //public DbSet<ClientUser> ClientUser { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        // moved migrations to Migrations folder
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new StudentConfiguration());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new MemberConfiguration());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new AddressConfiguration());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new PaymentConfiguration());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new PaymentTypeConfiguration());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ClientConfiguration());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ClientPaymentConfiguration());
    }
}
```

Client.cs

```
public class Client: DbEntityWithId
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Website { get; set; }
    public string Telephone { get; set; }
    public string Mobile { get; set; }
    public DateTime LicenseStart { get; set; }
    public DateTime LicenseEnd { get; set; }

    public bool IsSuspended { get; set; } = false;
    public int MemberLicense { get; set; }
    public string AdditionalInfo { get; set; }

    public int AddressId { get; set; }
    public virtual Address Address { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ClientPayment> ClientPayments { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUser> Users { get; set; }
}
```

FluentApi mapping:

```
public class ClientConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Client>
{
    public ClientConfiguration()
    {
        // create FK
        HasRequired<Address>(s => s.Address)
                .WithMany(s => s.Clients);

        HasMany<ApplicationUser>(s => s.Users)
            .WithMany(c => c.Clients)
            .Map(cs =>
            {
                cs.MapLeftKey("ClientId");
                cs.MapRightKey("UserId");
                cs.ToTable("ClientUser");
            });
    }
}
```

When executing the update-database command in Package Manager I get the following errors:

> MembershipManager.EntityFramework.Context.IdentityUserLogin: :
>   EntityType 'IdentityUserLogin' has no key defined. Define the key for
>   this EntityType.
>   MembershipManager.EntityFramework.Context.IdentityUserRole: :
>   EntityType 'IdentityUserRole' has no key defined. Define the key for
>   this EntityType. IdentityUserLogins: EntityType: EntitySet
>   'IdentityUserLogins' is based on type 'IdentityUserLogin' that has no
>   keys defined. IdentityUserRoles: EntityType: EntitySet
>   'IdentityUserRoles' is based on type 'IdentityUserRole' that has no
>   keys defined.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at the basics of custom IdentityDbContext: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/85741/identity-repository-pattern-with-unit-of-work/102087#102087

I think this topic is rather difficult especially if you try to work with several projects inside one solution. But working with IdentityDbContext will help you!